# Fill a table cell with input type="checkbox"

Tags: jquery, css, checkbox

I have table cells with checkboxes. What I want is the whole table cell to work as if you we're clicking the checkbox.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

---

### [CSS Method - JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NmPGg/)

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><label><input type="checkbox" /></label></td>
        <td><label><input type="checkbox" /></label></td>
        <td><label><input type="checkbox" /></label></td>
        <td><label><input type="checkbox" /></label></td>
        <td><label><input type="checkbox" /></label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label><input type="checkbox" /></label></td>
        <td><label><input type="checkbox" /></label></td>
        <td><label><input type="checkbox" /></label></td>
        <td><label><input type="checkbox" /></label></td>
        <td><label><input type="checkbox" /></label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label><input type="checkbox" /></label></td>
        <td><label><input type="checkbox" /></label></td>
        <td><label><input type="checkbox" /></label></td>
        <td><label><input type="checkbox" /></label></td>
        <td><label><input type="checkbox" /></label></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table{
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
td{
    padding:0px;
    border:solid 1px #000000;
}
label{
    display:block;
    padding:20px;
}
```

---

### [jQuery Method - JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/92byS/16/)

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table{
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
td{
    padding:20px;
    border:solid 1px #000000;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).on('click', 'td', function(){
    var target = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]');

    // If it's checked then uncheck it and vice versa
    target.prop('checked', !target.prop('checked'));
});
```

Comment: Points for the thoroughness of the answer!

Comment: The jQuery method, if you click exactly on the checkbox, it will not check it.

Comment: @PrabowoMurti Nice catch. I never tested that.

Comment: I am using `.children('input').click(function (e){e.stopPropagation()});` to make the checkbox doing nothing when clicked

Answer (score 2):

Why not try [**this method**](http://jsfiddle.net/gq6gB/1/)

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label><input type='checkbox' /></label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label><input type='checkbox' /></label>
        </td>
        <td>
             <label><input type='checkbox' /></label>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

CSS

```
td{
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid grey;
    overflow:hidden;
}
label{
    background:red;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    padding:50px;
    margin:-5px;
}
input{
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! this was a simple solution as always!

Answer (score 2):

Just use this to fill your td,

```
$('td').append($('<input/>',{'type':'checkbox'}));
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cnb54/1/)

For your reference:

- [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)
- [element creation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2)

---

Update:

use the following snippet to achieve your need,

```
$('td').click(function(){
    $(this).children('input').click();
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cnb54/2/)

Comment: OP already has checkboxes. OP is asking if there is a way to check the checkbox if the `<td>` is clicked.

Comment: No problem, sorry it took me so long to comment. if you would like to update your code then I will be happy to remove the downvote.

Comment: +1 to you too (I had to edit an error in my jQuery), whereas yours simply works by mimicking a click.